# Facebook Developer Account vs Facebook Personal Profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I would like to deactivate my personal Facebook profile.

The problem is that I have created a number of applications which are linked to the Facebook developer profile.

These applications do a number of things - provide authentication, service data requests with permissions from the API etc. These apps are used by some of my clients so it is important that these apps continue to function.

If I deactivate my personal account, what will happen to these apps?

Additionally, is it possible to keep the developer section active but deactivate the personal profile part of ones account?

Looking forward to the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you de-activate your account I doubt your apps will be impacted as deactivating your account can always be undone on facebook - so it's only a soft delete.

https://www.facebook.com/help/www/212666185422169

To be sure however, I would recommend creating an account for professional use and then assigning the admin of the application to this professional account. Then de-activating your personal account. You can add admins to the app by going to developers page for the app and clicking "Edit Roles". Once this new account is active and is the admin, you can remove your personal account as the admin.