# Delete Personal Facebook Keep Developer Account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

Is there a way to deactivate my personal account, but keep my developer account or create just a developer account that isn't tied to anything?  I don't want to delete my apps and want to continue to use facebook authentication.

I really want a break from facebook, but I can't find anything newer than about 5 years old outside of stack overflow without any real conclusions.  This answer is from 2014 on SO, but the person mentions they doubt and it's unclear what real way is.

[Facebook Developer Account vs Facebook Personal Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919980/facebook-developer-account-vs-facebook-personal-profile)

Comment: No that is not possible

Comment: You gotta pass your apps owner to other account in order to deactivate your personal account. If you try you might get this message `Unable to deactivate your account because you are the only developer of a Platform application. Please either delete the application or assign a new owner before deactivating your account.`

Comment: I hate that facebook locks you into this.  Thanks for the comments, I wish there was a way to just tie to a page